# Handle soap response from php toolkit

Tags: soap, httpresponse

I use force explorer to query datas, it works well.

**My query :**

```
`$query_result = $mySforceConnection->query("SELECT Metier__c, Profil__c, Secteur__c, TypeContrat__c, Id FROM Opportunity");`

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($query_result);
echo "</pre>";
```

**My response :**

```
object(QueryResult)[4]
```

public 'queryLocator' => string '01g2000001Mav0cAAB-2000' (length=23)
  public 'done' => boolean false
  public 'records' => 
    array (size=2000)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[6]
          public 'Id' => string '0062000000Ye3ZLAAZ' (length=18)
      1 => 
        object(stdClass)[7]
          public 'Id' => string '0062000000Ye3ZMAAZ' (length=18)
      2 => 
        object(stdClass)[8]
          public 'Id' => string '0062000000Ye3ZNAAZ' (length=18)
      3 => ...
     public 'size' => int 17202
  public 'pointer' => int 0
  private 'sf' => 
    object(SforceEnterpriseClient)[1]
      protected 'sforce' => 
        object(SoapClient)[2]
          public 'trace' => int 1
          public 'compression' => int 32
          public '_encoding' => string 'utf-8' (length=5)
          public '_features' => int 1
          public '_user_agent' => string 'salesforce-toolkit-php/27.0' (length=27)
          public '_soap_version' => int 1
          public 'sdl' => resource(10, Unknown)
          public '__last_request_headers' => string 'POST /services/Soap/c/27.0/00D20000000CpAr HTTP/1.1

Host: emea.salesforce.com

Connection: Keep-Alive

User-Agent: salesforce-toolkit-php/27.0

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8

SOAPAction: ""

Content-Length: 563

Cookie:

' (length=265)
          public '__last_response_headers' => string 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Date: Tue, 10 Feb 2015 09:51:02 GMT

Set-Cookie: BrowserId=Ph7Kgw0mQyCEBBahrCXleQ;Path=/;Domain=.salesforce.com;Expires=Sat, 11-Apr-2015 09:51:02 GMT

Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT

Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8

Content-Encoding: gzip

Content-Length: 17897

' (length=293)
          public '_cookies' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          public 'location' => string 'https://emea.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/27.0/00D20000000CpAr' (length=64)
          public '__default_headers' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          public '__last_request' => string '
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxSELECT Metier__c, Profil__c, Secteur__c, TypeContrat__c, Id FROM Opportunity resource(13, stream)
          public '_use_proxy' => int 0
          public 'httpurl' => resource(14, Unknown)

```
      ============== I WANT TO GET SECOND SOAP RESPONSE TO PARSE THIS ==

      public '__last_response' => string '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><queryResponse><result><done>false</done><queryLocator>01g2000001Mav0cAAB-2000</queryLocator><records xsi:type="sf:Opportunity"><sf:Id>0062000000Ye3ZLAAZ</sf:Id><sf:Metier__c>Maintenance Indus / Industrie Production</sf:Metier__c><sf:Profil_'... (length=531749)
  protected 'sessionId' => string '00D20000000CpAr!AQQAQIn39F2oRBB1oQK7.NcjV_K06gsa03Gc8j5Vud5k9XrOk_CJJsSFVaQZ7csDJUVUrQ5qoeepQs6QpCFR5UOGmRJzFsnd' (length=112)
```

As you see, i got a loong list of object as respnse, inside it i have 2 soap enveloppe.

MY QUESTION :
How can i get only the second soap response (inside public '__last_response')  so i can parse it after?

Thank for your help

Comment: Hello, i found it : $last_response = $mySforceConnection->getLastResponse()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to some formatting flaws in your question it's very hard to read and I was not able to fix it. If possible try to rework your indentation, so that the markdown here detects your response-dumps as source-code...

This said, generally I don't understand your approach at all. Why do you care about XML parsing at all when you get the response nicely packaged into php objects out of the box?

What I usually do is this:

```
require_once ('../yourPathTo/soapclient/SforcePartnerClient.php');
define("USERNAME", "you@wherever.com");
define("PASSWORD", "yourPassword");
define("SECURITY_TOKEN", "yourToken");
$GLOBALS[sfBatchSize] = 100;
$GLOBALS[sfConnection] = new SforcePartnerClient();
$GLOBALS[sfConnection]->createConnection("http://yourServer/yourPartnerWsdl..xml");
$GLOBALS[sfConnection]->setEndpoint('https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/31.0');
$GLOBALS[sfConnection]->login(USERNAME, PASSWORD.SECURITY_TOKEN);

$query = "SELECT Metier__c, Profil__c, Secteur__c, TypeContrat__c, Id FROM Opportunity ";
$response = $GLOBALS[sfConnection]->query($query);
$records = $response->records;
while(!$response->done) {
    $response = $GLOBALS[sfConnection]->queryMore($response->queryLocator);
    $records = array_merge($records, $response->records);    
}
```

Then in $records should be what you need.