# Wordpress integration - Need some expert advice

Tags: api, website-integration

What is the best way to publish content to a Wordpress site and make it available in Salesforce?

Looking for the best way to take sales training content, video and downloads that are published to a Wordpress site, and make it available inside Salesforce.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the SOAP API and since WordPress is a PHP solution at the Toolkit for PHP

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit

You could also have a look at some already answered questions about this toolkit, e.g.

- [Handle soap response from php toolkit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/65830/handle-soap-response-from-php-toolkit/65905#65905)
- [PHP API - Unable to query fields in custom objects](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/68277/php-api-unable-to-query-fields-in-custom-objects/68280#68280)